# UIView: how to update coordinates in XIB by program

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have subclassed and UIView in a class called Container.
I want to give the values of container frame by program.
To achieve this, in my Container class, I have a method called customInit as follow:

```
public func customInit() {
        super.customInit()
        backgroundColor = .systemCyan
        frame.origin.x = 10
    }
```

(of course it's not so simple, I just want to give an example). To interact with IB, I have in my Container class:

```
override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        customInit()
    }
```

So that the changes I make in customInit is reflected in IB.
[this is what I see in IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDPNr.png)

But if I select the view in IB, I obtain this:
[what I see when container is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUAGw.png)

the container view is well positioned, but when I select it IB shows another position.
I understand that the values I see in IB Inspector are never updated in the XIB file
[values in IB Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctn0p.png)

if there are multiple container views included in the contentView, this can become a real problem (think for instance to a keyboard view, where each key is represented by a Container class)

So my question is: Is it possible to update the XIB file, or at least have IB showing the correct position when the view is selected?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly in the way you load and initialize your XIB view, but you haven't shown that code.

There are various approaches to this, including extensions and "helpers."

Here is a very simple, basic example. The XIB rounds its corners and adds a border, and has an `@IBOutlet` label. It includes `@IBDesignable` properties for the label string, the background color and the border color:

It looks like this in IB:

[image]

and, after changing a couple of the `@IBInspectable` properties:

[image]

**BasicXIBView.xib**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="BasicXIBView" customModule="QuickTest" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="testLabel" destination="a7l-k8-xno" id="4zG-1N-QR0"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="229"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="a7l-k8-xno">
                    <rect key="frame" x="139.5" y="104.5" width="41.5" height="20.5"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.97609727989999995" green="1" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="displayP3"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="a7l-k8-xno" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="centerY" id="854-s5-92e"/>
                <constraint firstItem="a7l-k8-xno" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="centerX" id="lpT-0r-6vc"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-91.875" y="249.375"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

**BasicXIBView.swift**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class BasicXIBView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var str: String = "Test Label" {
        didSet {
            testLabel.text = str
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var bkgColor: UIColor = .systemTeal {
        didSet {
            xibView.backgroundColor = bkgColor
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var brdColor: UIColor = .systemBlue {
        didSet {
            xibView.layer.borderColor = brdColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var testLabel: UILabel!
    
    // reference to the view object loaded from the XIB / NIB
    var xibView: UIView!
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        if xibView == nil {
            guard let cv = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).loadNibNamed(String(describing: type(of: self)), owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView else {
                return
            }
            self.insertSubview(cv, at: 0)
            cv.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            cv.frame = bounds
            xibView = cv
        }
        
        // rounded corners, single pt border
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = 20
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        // IBInspectable properties
        testLabel.text = str
        xibView.backgroundColor = bkgColor
        layer.borderColor = brdColor.cgColor
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I didn't understand how a change to your variable XibView will update the XIB file

Comment: thank you for your response, but I don't understand how a change to your variable XibView will update the XIB file
 in my App, I don't use Xib files but a storyboard (perhaps it is better to use XIB files?)
I instantiate the view controller (which will contain the subclassed view called LoginContainer) by calling in the sceneDelegate:
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:  
    Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController")

I don't understand howto make the link in my subclass with the storyboard file
(not sure to be clear enough)

Comment: @PatriceRapaport - sorry, you stated: *"So my question is: Is it possible to update the XIB file..."* so I assumed you **are** using Xib files. You'll need to post your complete class (or, at least a minimal version) that demonstrates the issue in order for us to help you with your code.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstood. So I will make another post with title: Is it possible to update the storyboard (I call it a XIB file, but sure, you are right)